# 'tag' field jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a popup menu with jQuery with some buttons. Number of buttons is flexibel. For each item in the variable 'items' there is one button. The problem: If the button is clicked I want to know to which item it belongs to.

In other programming languages there is a so called 'tag'-field where you can put an integer or an object for identification. What is the best way in jQuery?

```
var popup = $('<div />');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    var btn = $('<div>' + items.Name + '</div>').appendTo(popup).button().click(
        function(e) {
            // alert($(e.target).tag);
            popup.hide();
        }
    );
    // btn.tag = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at `.data()`. This will allow you to store information associated with a `key` for any element.

```
var popup = $('<div />');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    var btn = $('<div>' + items.Name + '</div>').appendTo(popup).button().click(
        function(e) {
            // alert($(e.target).tag);
            popup.hide();
        }
    );
    btn.data("index", i);
}
```

You can the retrieve the information using `btn.data("index")` where `btn` is a jQuery object containing the element.

### Update - Accessing the element that has been clicked within a function

The `this` keyword will refer to the html element that has been clicked. You could alert the stored data using:

```
function(e){
   alert($(this).data("index"));
}
```

Comment: But I dont have the jQuery object in the click-function. So if I try to get my 'i' with $(e.target).data("index") I get an 'undefined' as answere.

Comment: @user1027167: answer updated to show accessing `data` within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "data-" attribute...

```
var popup = $('<div />');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    var btn = $('<div ' + 'data-tag="' + i + '">' + items.Name + '</div>').appendTo(popup).button().click(
        function(e) {
            // alert($(e.target).tag);
            alert($(this).data("tag"));
            popup.hide();
        }
    );
    // btn.tag = i;
}
```

Comment: please see my (first) comment at the answere of Smirkin Gherkin